# React/CSS - Aligning Images, Button, and Text in a column

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, axios

[image]

Currently, in my app, when I click on the button, it generates a random image but it bunches up everything like so. I'd like the image to show up, which are all in different sizes, have the dog's name right below it, centered and then the button below that.

**Code**

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {

  const [images, setImage] = React.useState("");
  const [text, setText]    = React.useState("");

  function btnClick() {

    axios
        .all([axios.get("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random"), 
              axios.get("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all")
         ]) 
        .then(axios.spread((response) => {
              setImage(response.data.message);
              setText(response.data.message.split('/')[4]);
         }))     
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("Error happened during fetching!", err);
        });
  }

  return (
    <div className = "App">
      <img    className = "Img"    src={images} alt="broken"/>
      <button className = "Button" onClick = {btnClick}>Doggie!</button>
      <strong>{text}</strong>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**CSS**

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.Button {
  display: flex;
}

.Img {
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
  max-height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Re-arranging the element should solve the issue, wrap the name with `<p></p>` to display it on a new paragraph.

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [images, setImage] = React.useState("");
  const [text, setText] = React.useState("");

  function btnClick() {
    axios
    .all([
      axios.get("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random"),
      axios.get("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all")
    ])
    .then(
      axios.spread(response => {
        setImage(response.data.message);
        setText(response.data.message.split("/")[4]);
      })
    )
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("Error happened during fetching!", err);
    });
 }

 return (
   <div className="App">
    <img src={images} alt="broken" />
    <p><strong>{text}</strong></p>
    <button className="button" onClick={btnClick}>
     Doggie!
    </button>
   </div>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should rearrange your rendered elements, so it goes `<img/> <strong/> <button />`.

Then in your CSS, make sure the elements that are `inline` natively become `block`.

See snippet below. 
**Note:** left out React as it's not related to your issue so ignore `class` usage.

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.App strong {
  display: block;
}

.Button {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.Img {
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
  max-height:100%;
  display: block;
}
<div class="App">
  <img class="Img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WaeI.png" alt="broken"/>
  <strong>{text}</strong>
  <button class="Button" onClick={btnClick}>Doggie!</button>
</div>
```

### Flexbox

If you would prefer to use flexbox styling [see this thorough post about it](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: appreciate the help, i just realized that it's not following the image and planting the text & button right below it. Some images are of different sizes and the button is fixed in that centered spot. I'd like for it to be centered relative to the image